# how do i restructure this code so i dont get a branch out of range error

Tags: assembly, dragonboard

Im creating an elevator system using a dragon12-plus2 board. So far everything works except for a specific branch out of range error. any help? thanks in advance

Input of the system - push button
Output of the system - lcd and 7-segments

[image: the output of the code when run]

errors occur at lines 86, 88, 90, 143, 145, 147, 200, 202, 204

```
#include &quot;C:\miniide\hcs12.inc&quot;
org $2000
lcd_dat equ PORTK ; LCD data pins (PK5~PK2)
lcd_dir equ DDRK ; LCD data direction port
lcd_E equ $02 ; E signal pin
lcd_RS equ $01 ; RS signal pin
movb #$0, DDRH
movb #$FF, DDRB
movb #$FF, DDRP
lds #$2000 ; initialize stack pointer
F2T1 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
ldx #downward ; display a message (downward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$06, PTB ; display 1
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
floor1 ldab PTH
cmpb #%11111101
lbeq F1T2
cmpb #%11111011
lbeq F1T3
cmpb #%11110111
lbeq F1T4
bra floor1
F3T1 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
ldx #downward ; display a message (downward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$5B, PTB ; display 2
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$06, PTB ; display 1
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
bra floor1
F4T1 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
ldx #downward ; display a message (downward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$4F, PTB ; display 3

movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$5B, PTB ; display 2
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$06, PTB ; display 1
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
jsr floor1
F1T2 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #upward ; display a message (upward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$5B, PTB ; display 2
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
floor2 ldab PTH
cmpb #%11111110
beq F2T1
cmpb #%11111011
beq F2T3
cmpb #%11110111
beq F2T4
bra floor2
F3T2 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #downward ; display a message (downward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$5B, PTB ; display 2
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
bra floor2
F4T2 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #downward ; display a message (downward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$4F, PTB ; display 3

movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$5B, PTB ; display 2
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
bra floor2
F1T3 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #upward ; display a message (upward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$5B, PTB ; display 2
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$4F, PTB ; display 3
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
floor3 ldab PTH
cmpb #%11111110
beq F3T1
cmpb #%11111101
beq F3T2
cmpb #%11110111
beq F3T4
bra floor3
F2T3 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #upward ; display a message (upward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$4F, PTB ; display 3
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
bra floor3
F4T3 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #downward ; display a message (downward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$4F, PTB ; display 3
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1

ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
bra floor3
F1T4 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #upward ; display a message (upward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$5B, PTB ; display 2
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$4F, PTB ; display 3
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$66, PTB ; display 4
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
floor4 ldab PTH
cmpb #%11111110
beq F4T1
cmpb #%11111101
beq F4T2
cmpb #%11111011
beq F4T3
bra floor4
F2T4 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #upward ; display a message (upward)
jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$4F, PTB ; display 3
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$66, PTB ; display 4
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
bra floor4
F3T4 ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCDjsr cmd2lcd ; &quot;
ldx #upward ; display a message (upward)

jsr putsLCD
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
movb #$66, PTB ; display 4
movb #$FE, PTP ; using 7seg #1
ldy #100
jsr delayby10ms
jsr openLCD ; initialize the LCD
lbra floor4
upward dc.b &quot;upward&quot;,0
downward dc.b &quot;downward&quot;,0
#include &quot;c:\miniide\delay.asm&quot; ; delay routines
#include &quot;c:\miniide\lcd.asm&quot; ; LCD routines
end
```

i tried restructuring the code multiple ways, still the same branch error

Comment: I don't speak dragon, but if this were x86, I'd be thinking about replacing `beq F2T3` with `bne over1 | jmp F2T3 | over1` under the assumption that non-conditional jumps might have fewer limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add structure to your assembler. Think in larger code blocks,
isolate functions and procedures, clearly label entry points.

```
EntryXYZ: // a little bit of code
          // more code

EntryYZW: // a lot of code

EntryZZZ: // a little bit of code
```

Between every small function you can add trampolines:

```
JumpPoint1:  jmp Label
SmallCode:  test ax,ax
            bne JumpPoint1
            // more code
            jle skip0
            jmp Label
skip:       // more code
```

In long code one needs to use the `jNOTcond skip; jmp Label; skip:` paradigm. In short code one can use the `jCOND trampoline` paradigm.

Also one can place these jump points in the middle of long code as in:

```
  bne skip:
  jmp longJump
tramp1:
  jmp longJumpA
tramp2:
  jmp longJumpB
skip:
```

One more technique is to locate an earlier branch to the same target, as in

```
tramp_label_bne_002:
  bne tramp_label_bne_001:
Code:
  // max 126 bytes of code
  bne tramp_label_bne002
```